# Ruby `&&` vs `and` in a block

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

In the code below, if I replace the `and` in the `any?` statement with `&&`, it throws an error `unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'`.

```
def ArrayAddition(arr)
  i = 2
  until i == arr.length
    combinations = arr.permutation(i).to_a
    return true if combinations.any?{|array| array.inject(&:+) == arr.max and !array.include? arr.max}
    i+=1
  end
    false
end
```

What is going on here? Does Ruby handle these operators differently?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `and` has lower precedence than `&&` (and [almost everything else](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)). This expression:

```
foo and bar baz
```

...is parsed like this:

```
foo and (bar baz)
```

...so Ruby knows `foo` is a method name (because it can't be anything else). On the other hand, this expression:

```
foo && bar baz
```

...is parsed like this:

```
(foo && bar) baz
```

...which just doesn't make sense and you get a syntax error.

Generally speaking you should use `&&` unless you specifically want `and`'s lower precedence, so in this case the easiest fix to the syntax error is to use parentheses around the method argument:

```
foo && bar(baz)
```

...and so:

```
array.inject(&:+) == arr.max && !array.include?(arr.max)
```

As a bonus, this is more readable as well.

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please take a moment to explain the reason for your downvote. If there's a problem with my answer I'd appreciate the opportunity to improve it.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Much appreciated!

Comment: @Jordan, somebody has bad mood today)

Answer (score 3):

The operators `and` and `&&` have different precedence, and are not equivalent.  As such, the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) advises against using `and` and `or` operators: [The and and or keywords are banned. It's just not worth it. Always use && and || instead.](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or)

Due to the difference in precedence, the other operators in the expression have higher or lower comparative precedence.  In this case, the argument for the `Array#include?` call end up binding to the wrong expression.

You can solve this by adding parentheses around the argument to the `Array#include?` call.

Comment: If you have something constructive to add to the answer, please comment.  Arbitrary anonymous downvotes do nothing to improve the quality of the answers.

Comment: Upvoted to counteract whatever troll has decided to inflict themselves upon us tonight (I have a guess...), and for the style guide link.

Comment: Thanks, @Jordan - I have no idea who it might be.  I'd certainly prefer constructive feedback to improve the answer.  But I guess it's easier (and maybe more satisfying) to just downvote an answer and move on...

Comment: *"Always use && and || instead."* is quite harsh. `and` and `or` work great for control flow.